# Are the cabin fuse-box relays misplaced in my Renault Kangoo?

Tags: electrical, troubleshooting, renault, relay, kangoo

I have a Renault Kangoo 2009. 1.6 liter petrol, automatic. The cabin blower motor has stopped working. The fuses seems ok, but a relay in the fuse-box under the "glove-box" recess could have gone missing somehow. The Renault handbook lists fuses, but not relays. It should be pointed out though that the 4th and 5th positions are not wired. My question is how many relays are there supposed to be? Two or three? If two, where are they meant to be located? And last, what colors should the relays have? The below picture shows the layout of the fuse-box.
[image: Kangoo 2009 cabin fuse-box content]

Update 1: Have through trial and error established that the first relay position (from left) concerns the heating of the rear window. That the third relay position concerns the motorized side windows. The second relay position, however, is still a mystery. Maybe some of you guys know what the purpose with it is?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score -1):

https://www.autogenius.info/renault-kangoo-1997-2007-fuse-box-diagram/amp/

Didn't look real close. Maybe this link will help.

Comment: This is a "link only" answer. Please bring the information here along with the link for reference.

Comment: Thx for your link. It was, however, not too helpful. Non of the diagrams matched my fusebox layout.